# Scan Mishneh Torah

Tags: rambam, mishneh-torah

I'm looking a scan (photo) of paper (Mishneh Torah, Sefer Nashim, Ishut 3,11) translated by the rabbi Rabbi Eliyahu Touger. Can someone please send me this page? I need it for a translation comparison-research. I can't find it anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: It is online here in English and Hebrew https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952876/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Three.htm

Comment: But I requested the original paper version (scan) and therefore with page reference. This online version is not useful to me.

Comment: Hope someone can attach the scanned page. Thanks

Comment: you did request it but I don’t have it … the online has the same content incl references

Comment: I know, thank you anyway. However, I am looking for an original scan of the paper version and with page number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Thanks to Yekutiel for the scans.

The topic can be closed.

Comment: Click on the checkmark next to your answer and that will signal that your answer is satisfactory.